# How to compress all the files into one tar.gz file before copying from remote servers?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scp, gnu-parallel

I have around 2000 files residing on remote server, each file size around 10 GB and I want to copy all those 2000 files from remote server. I can use `GNU parallel` to parallelize my scp and copy them in parallel with 5 files at a time. But is there any way by which I can tar all 2000 files in one `files.tar.gz` and then copy that tar.gz file and then after copying uncompressed them? This will reduce the copying time for me and it will be very fast. I want to do this tar and untar from my script which will copy the files from remote servers.

```
do_Copy() {
  el=$1
  PRIMSEC=$2
  df /data01 | awk 'NR>1 {gsub(/%/,""); if ($5 > 90) {exit 1}}' || { echo "exiting as we ran out of space" >&2 && exit 1; }
  scp user@"$LOCAL":"$dir3"/process_"$el"_try.data "$PRIMSEC"/. || { touch "$status_dir/local_down" && scp user@"$PRIMARY":"$dir3"/process_"$el"_try.data "$PRIMSEC"/.; } || { touch "$status_dir/primary_down" && scp user@"$SECONDARY":"$dir3"/process_"$el"_try.data "$PRIMSEC"/.; } || { touch "$status_dir/secondary_down" && exit 1; }
}
export -f do_Copy

parallel -j 5 do_Copy {} $DATA ::: ${SHARDS[@]} &
wait
```

In my above script, I am copying from `LOCAL` server first but if that `LOCAL` server is down, then I will copy from `PRIMARY` server and if that is down too then I will copy from `SECONDARY` server.

Comment: Remove the `&` and then you do not need the `wait`.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: @jww: is writing bash code no programming or no development?

Comment: Your question concerns itself with the `tar` command over `ssh`. If it was reduced to its minimal example, the command is the only thing that would remain. Forgive me if I am missing something in the questions.

Comment: If your network is unreliable to the point that you need backup servers, it doesn't seem very sensible to create a 20TB file to copy because your network is unlikely to stay up long enough. I would go for multiple smaller shards which are more likely to be able to use your entire network bandwidth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `scp`, use `rsync` with the option `-z` for compressing the data when copying.

See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/70581/scp-and-compress-at-the-same-time-no-intermediate-save for more explanation.

Comment: So you mean to say I can write my above scp line with this line instead `rsync -z user@"$LOCAL":"$dir3"/process_"$el"_try.data "$PRIMSEC"/. || { touch "$status_dir/local_down" && scp user@"$PRIMARY":"$dir3"/process_"$el"_try.data "$PRIMSEC"/.; } || { touch "$status_dir/primary_down" && scp user@"$SECONDARY":"$dir3"/process_"$el"_try.data "$PRIMSEC"/.; } || { touch "$status_dir/secondary_down" && exit 1; }` That's all and everything should work as it is then?

Comment: I will check in the manual of `rsync` and `scp`, but if you are in a hurry, you could do it also by yourself.

Comment: First of all, be aware that you have several instances of scp in your command line. Secondly, will not code everything for you, because your code doesn't include enough commentaries for explaining what you do. What I will do is to put the syntax of `scp` near the syntax of `rsync`:

`scp user@host:path localpath`

seems to be equivalent to:

`rsync -z -e "ssh -l user" rsync-user@host:path localpath`

but with data compression enabled. I wonder if the rsync-user is the same as the ssh user. You will have to experiment when you install `rsync`.